# Disable Gallery View

Tags: java, android, gallery

I have a problem disabling views from my Gallery in my Android application. Nothing seems to happen with the View when I click it. Here is my `onItemClick(...)` method:

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
   int position, long id) {
        view.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

I have also tried `setVisibility(...)`
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose that your entire onItemClick method is not invoked.

Comment: I could be completely wrong but isn't the view in the onItemClick the view thats inflated ans see and not the actual click area that you've clicked on. That may sound weird, but i believe the click area is different from the view that you actually see in the cell. So setting view.setEnabled(false) won't actually change the state of what your clicking. This is an assumption.

Comment: @fiction: It is invoked. I can get the correct ID of the View and everything.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set your view invisible, try this little piece of code:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This sets the view invisible and i think you can't focus it anymore. But if you're working within a grid, there will be a gap left behind.

Comment: This works as long as you don't scroll past the gap it leaves behind. If I do so, the View reappears.